# I don't receive notifications about new emails

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot

I set up postfix + dovecot, and everything works, but I don't get notifications about new messages, the inbox is updated only when I open Outlook or another client, perhaps need to use some MDA?
in the nginx logs, the bug will ask for this format
"OPTIONS /Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync?Cmd=Options&User=user%40domen&DeviceId=42fb0cb987c44ab699b3227fa3cfc76c&DeviceType=Outlook HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Outlook-iOS-Android/1.0" "-"

dovecot -n

```
auth_cache_negative_ttl = 0
auth_cache_size = 50 M
auth_mechanisms = plain login
first_valid_uid = 150
last_valid_uid = 150
mail_gid = mail
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_uid = vmail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster at deleted
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/deleted/fullchain.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

postfix -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 550
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 3h
milter_default_action = accept
milter_mail_macros = i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
milter_protocol = 6
minimal_backoff_time = 180s
mydestination = localhost
mydomain = deleted
myhostname = deleted
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
non_fqdn_reject_code = 550
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11332
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_helo_timeout = 15s
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 15s
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions = 127.0.0.0/8
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:11332
smtpd_recipient_limit = 40
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_timeout = 30s
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live//fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live//privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_sender_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/sql/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```